# Excel Pie chart Not showing all Data (Count

Tags: excel, pie-chart

I'm trying to figure why my pie chart in the image attached will not show all of the data in column A. In column A, I have numbers 1-5, and in some cells I have "No score", For some reason I can only get the pie chart to show 1-3. I would like for the pie chart to show many how many 1's, how many 2's, etc.

I tried reselecting data looking at the pie chart format but have found no solution.

[image]

Comment: You need to group those numbers and then use a chart, best way to do it is using `Pivot Table` and `Pivot Chart` ! Put those numbers once in the `Rows` Area of `Pivot Table` and once in `Values` Area.

Comment: Use the frequency() function, does all that counting without Pivot XXX - much better to be able to do things manually and understand where things come from.

Comment: `Frequency` ignores blank cells and text, so won't pick up on the No Score entries.  I guess you could use it for the numbers and then a COUNTIF for the text.